# IP and Domain Based Virtual Hosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost, vps

My VPS is giving me 16 IP v6 addresses, and I want to host 16 domains and I want them in such a way that each domain has its own unique ipv6 address.

If I wanted to do this, how would I proceed ? A lot of research tells me that I should use Virtual Hosts, is this how it is to be done ? Should I use a simple panel like webmin instead ?

Comment: I was using nginx, but a lot of the worries was solved when I used VestaCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Apache, it's pretty straightforward.  Follow the instructions at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html using ipv6 notation (ipv6 address in square brackets) instead of naked ipv4 addresses.  Make sure to have a `Listen` directive for each of the 16 addresses, and a `VirtualHost` section for each as well.

e.g.:

```
Listen [2001:0db8:100::1]:80

<VirtualHost [2001:0db8:100::1]:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ...more config here...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could map your IPV6 addresses to domain names in DNS

[2001:0db8:100::1 -> Domain1
[2001:0db8:100::2 -> Domain2

And use Name Based Virtual Hosts in Apache which makes accessing the application via browsers more readable: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.domain2.com
 DocumentRoot /www/domain2
</VirtualHost>
```